# Should I use d3.js to draw lines between paragraphs of text?

Tags: text, d3.js, web, draw

I intend to create a system with two columns of text. There will be lines that indicate connections between some paragraphs on the left with some paragraphs on the right that appear when you mouseover them. Should I be using d3.js or is that overkill for this purpose?

EDIT: to be clear, some of the paragraphs on the left may not be aligned with the ones on the right so there would be crossing diagonal lines all along the middle.

Comment: CSS has transforms and that gives you a lot of flexibility.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Krzysztof is correct in that you might want to consider more complex interactions in the future. If you really just need a line, though, then D3.js is definitely overkill. Several commenters have suggested CSS borders, but I don't know if that approach meets your needs. If you want to draw straight lines between paragraphs, those lines won't, presumably, always be strictly horizontal or vertical. A more flexible option would be to add an absolutely positioned `<div>` into the page, hiding or showing it as appropriate. The `<div>` can have a `1px` height and a background color to simulate a line, and it can be transformed using translation and rotation to connect any two arbitrary points.

Comment: Ah this is what I was looking for them, a div with transformations! Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

No, use CSS instead. If you provide HTML code then we can guide you with CSS. Check out CSS borders: http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_border.asp

Comment: What if I need a line between the 5th paragraph on the left and the 2nd paragraph on the right?

Answer (score 1):

it depends on many factors. If you need d3.js only for 'draw lines/arrows'  then I think this is overkill (d3.js is bigger then jquery). This looks like some simple task with basic tools. But if this is data presentation, which in future may be more complex, and when you use d3 for other charts, it will be fine.

Edit: because OP edit:
Look at this in semantic way. If this is data presentation then yes, If this is graphic effect then no.

Comment: Well there is data in the sense that the text is data, but not the number data that I think is implied. So I guess it's just graphic. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

No. D3 = "Data-Driven Documents".  D3 uses SVG, and adding an SVG into your page just to draw a line is an absolute overkill.  As a rule, you should take the simplest approach, hence a CSS border should do the job

```
border-bottom: 2px solid red;
```

for example.